# How to make string act like a variable name?

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables

I've seen many other questions like this but none of them helped in my case, I don't feel my question is duplicate for this reason. All questions regarding this case try to attach a new "meaning" to the string variable, while I already have those variables, just want to use a string to be able to reach those pre-existing variables.

I have few divs with IDs and few dictionaries in JS with the names being the same as those IDs. I want to take those IDs, which are returned as strings, and use them as variables to access those dictionaries.

I tried using `window[item.id] = idName` but I believe I don't understand it, as it doesn't work.

My code:

```html
<div id="id1" onclick="myfunc(this)"></div>
<div id="id2" onclick="myfunc(this)"></div>
<div id="id3" onclick="myfunc(this)"></div>
```

```js
/* pre-existing variables I want to be able to use with IDs taken from function*/
id1={"name":"xxxx"}
id2={"name":"yyyy"}
id3={"name":"zzzz"}
 
function myfunc(item){
idName=item.id//returns string with id name
name=idName["name"]//doesn't work, as idName is a string and doesn't behave as a variable name;
}
```

Comment: If `id1`, `id2` and `id3` are in global scope, you can get them from `window`. Like `window[idName]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `dictionary` first

Then you can take `id`'s object...

```js
const dictionary = {
    id1: {name: 'xxxx'},
    id2: {name: 'yyyy'},
    id3: {name: 'zzzz'},
};

const myfunc = (item)=>{
    const idName = item.id;
    const aName = dictionary[idName];
    console.log(aName.name);
};
```

```html
<div id="id1" onclick="myfunc(this)">one</div>
<div id="id2" onclick="myfunc(this)">one but 2</div>
<div id="id3" onclick="myfunc(this)">the third</div>
```